# means/pvalue table from t.test in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract the mean and p-value from a t.test output and create a table that includes the features, mean, and p-value? Say there are 10 columns put through t.test, and that means there are 10 means, and 10 p-values. How would I be able to create a table which only shows those specific items?

here is an example: data (iris):

```
    a.   b.  c.  d.   e. 
1   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
2   4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
3   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
4   4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
5   5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
6   5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 setosa

t.test(a)
t.test(b) #...ect we obtain the mean and p-value.
```

this is the output im looking for:

```
feature mean p-val
col1  0.01 0.95
col2  0.01 0.95
.
.
.
coln
```

hope it makes sense!

Comment: Do not post images of code or data. We cannot copy data from images into R for testing. See [how to include data in a reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't get the aim.. you are testing the mean of each column is not zero?

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you the output as desired - please accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the iris built in data set as an example

```
t(sapply(iris[, 1:4], function(i){
  t.test(i)[c(5,3)]
}))
```

The `sapply()` function is iteratively performing that custom function - which performs a t-test on a variable and returns the estimate and p-value - through columns 1 to 4 of iris. That is then transposed by `t()` to rotate the data to the desired shape. You can store that as a data.frame using `data.frame()` and use `row.names()` to get the variable names into a new column on that if you like.

```
values <- t(sapply(iris[, 1:4], function(i){
  t.test(i)[c(5,3)]
}))

values <- data.frame("feature"=row.names(values), values)
row.names(values) <- NULL
values
```

Beware multiple testing though...